# Correct implementation of comparator function in C not working as expected

Tags: c, pointers

I was testing an implementation of a comparator function. So here's my code that **worked**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int compare_names(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    char* sa = (char*) a;
    char* sb = (char*) b;
    return strcmp(sa, sb);
}  

int main()
{
    char *a = "Bianca";
    char *b = "Ana";
    printf("Comparing %s with %s returns: %i\n", a, b, compare_names(a, b)); 
    return 0;
}
```

But I don't think it's right as `a` and `b` arguments at `compare_names` function should turn out to be a pointer to a pointer of char. As pointed in a book I've read, the correct code for the `compare_names` function would be

```
int compare_names(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    char** sa = (char**) a;
    char** sb = (char**) b;
    return strcmp(*sa, *sb);
}
```

But when I ran the code I got a segmentation fault (core dumped).

What am I missing here?

EDIT: I'm using gcc on Linux x64.

Comment: Probably the context of the code in your book was different. With different context (e. g. other data types, other data relations and nesting etc.), you can (and will) get different code.

Comment: Presumably the code in the book appeared in the context of a qsort comparator or similar, where that would make sense.  In that case it should be called like `compare_names(&a, &b)`.

Comment: @glglgl That's what I was thinking.

Comment: @TavianBarnes That's the context of a qsort indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int compare_names(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    char** sa = (char**) a;
    char** sb = (char**) b;
    return strcmp(*sa, *sb);
} 

int main()
{
    char *a = "Bianca";
    char *b = "Ana";
    printf("Comparing %s with %s returns: %i\n", a, b, compare_names(&a, &b)); 
    return 0;
}
```

Now it's ok. You have to put the address of `a` and `b` in the `printf` parameters, since there are casted to `char**`.

Comment: That works but my first implementation was flaw? If it was not , that corrected second solution is much more verbose.

Comment: @kaneda Your first implementation is correct. The two functions will produce the same output. In which case the second one is used in your book ? The only advantage of the second one is that you can change the value of `a` and `b`. Pick the more convenient in your case.

Comment: The version with the void pointers looks like it's meant to be used with qsort(); if that is the case, the reason it that its comparison function takes pointers to the elements of the array to be sorted, so if you have an array of strings, it will take a pointer t o string (string being a pointer to char)

Answer (score 1):

`char** sa = (char**) a;` This line says: "If you direference twice your `sa` you will end up with a `char`" The problem is that since your `a` is a pointer to char you can not direference it twice. So the casting you are doing is generally wrong.

When casting, the compiler trys to interpret your `*a` which is a `char` as a pointer to char so when the conversion is performed your `*sa` ends up being a BadPtr since it fails to convert from `char` to `char *`.

So in your `strcmp()` you have two BadPtr.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing char* arguments, not char** arguments. The example code you posted showing char** does the following:

```
1. Change generic pointer to a pointer to a string.
2. Compare the strings by dereferencing the char** arguments, meaning you're passing char* arguments to strcmp and return the result.
```

But you passed char* arguments to your comparison function, so the dereferencing ends up passing arguments of type char to strcmp. Since it expects pointers, the char is interpreted as a memory address. Comparing "hello" to "bye" actually compares the string at address 0x67 to the string at address 0x62, which will segfault.

Pass &a and &b to your comparison function to make it not segfault.

Answer (score 0):

Both versions should work, however, for the second version of the "campare_names" function, you should pass an aditional pointer to each of the char pointers when calling the function.

However your version of the function is correct, it only makes sence to use double pointer parameters, when you are expecting that a function wil alter the pointer position or data being pointed. In this case, since the strcmp function only reads the char* data and doesn't make any changes to it, you don't need an aditional pointer.